# Integrals with substitution rule

Tags: integration

I need to compute the following integrals with the substitution rule, but I don't have a clue where to start:
$$\int e^{-(2x^{2}+1)}x\, dx$$
and
$$\int x (3x^2-2)^7 \, dx.$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int e^{-(2x^{2}+1)}x\, dx$$

Let $u = -2x^2 - 1 \implies du = -4x \,dx \iff -\frac 14 \,du = x\,dx$

This gives us the integral $$\int e^{-(2x^{2}+1)}x\, dx = -\frac 14 \int e^u\,du$$

---

$$\int x (3x^2-2)^7 \, dx.$$

Let $u = 3x^2 - 2 \implies du = 6x\,dx \iff \frac 16\,du = x\,dx$

This gives us $$\int x (3x^2-2)^7 \, dx = \frac 16\int u^7\,du$$

Answer (score 3):

In the first integral, the presence of $x=\frac{1}{2}D x^2$ suggests the substitution $2x^2+1=u$, so that $4x \, dx = du$

In the second integral, you can try $3x^2-2=u$, so that $6x \, dx = du$.

Then, in both cases, you replace $x \, dx$ by the suitable expression in terms of $du$ and the two integrals become easy.